# Set List item in number of Dropdownlist

Tags: arrays, drop-down-menu

I have 12 Nos of Dropdown list on a asp page, Named `ddlGp01, ddlGp02......ddlGp12`, with a populated list of items.

I I have array of Integer Called `DivAllotted`
I am unable to select list item through a subroutine call.

Code is in VB.net

Array of list item values is `DivAllotted`

I have to programmatically select a list item in these drop downlist.

I tried this

```
Dim ddlGp as DropDownList
for N=0 to 12
    ddlGp.ID= "ddlGp" & (N).ToString("00")
    SetGpsAllotted(ddlGp, DivAllotted(N))
next
```

Subroutine `SetGpsAllotted` is as under

```
Sub SetGpsAllotted(ByVal ddl as DropDownList, ByVal DivID as Integer) 
   ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.items.FindByValue(DivID))
End Sub
```

This is not showing any error not selecting list item even . pl suggest